# Should we use CSS child selectors or CSS class based selector?

Tags: html, css, html-rendering, web-optimization

Which one is the better way to select the child div in following HTML code in terms of performance and optimizations?

**Options 1:**

```
<div class="parent-div">
  <div></div> <!--- child DIV !--->
</div>
```

// CSS

```
.parent-div > div {
  // Some CSS for child div
}
```

'

**Options 2:** (selecting using a className/id)

```
<div class="parent-div">
   <div class="child-div"></div>
</div>
```

// CSS

```
 .child-div {
    // Some CSS for child div
 }
```

Comment: Second option will be better for performance because it will only find target element by class name to apply css instead of finding on child div.

Comment: @Priyajain The performance benefit would be negligible.

Answer (score 3):

Option 2 is way better for code maintainability.

I recommend reading [the BEM naming convention guide](http://getbem.com/naming/).

```
<div class="block">
   <div class="block__elem"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: a very useful resource, but unfortunately most of the HTML templates that are sold and distributed in the market are assigned CSS properties throughes the parent elements.

Comment: You are right about that. However whenever i'm fully in control of the codebase i try to stick to the BEMguidelines!

Answer (score 0):

That depends, if the child is "component" of its own, I would give it a class. but if it is just being a part of some parent component, I would use the `.class > element` option.

My point of view is based on Angular and its CSS separated on a component level. The benefit of that is, that you will not end up with an overwhelming file.